# Fullscreen video on chrome do a fullscreen on the website

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

i try to allow the fullscreen mode on youtube video, it's work well on IE and Firefox, but on Chrome, it's not the video, but the website who is display in fullscreen.

I use Zerif.

I try those following way :

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin:8px">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bO2sbzgo4wQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin:8px">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wCc2v7izk8w"  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen  allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin:8px">

    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
    <script>
      // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
      // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
        });
      }
    </script>
</div>
```

I also try with `<object>` but every time it works on IE and Firefox when chrome do a fullscreen on the website.

Sorry for my english and thanks for help.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome. It has been reported in the past, but no news yet.

It is caused by YouTube's HTML5 player. You can fix this by forcing the use of the old Flash player.

Go to [this site](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/youtube_xhtml/) to generate the embed code.

Not the best solution, but I hope it helps!

UPDATE: You may be able to force the fullscreen video using javascript if you use `<iframe>`. Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1) API documentation for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when i use the generated code, i have a grey square instead of the video in firefox and IE. But the correct representation in chrome, but when i click on play or other button on video on chrome, nothing happens, an idea ?